# How to make join on 3 table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, querydsl

I am using `QueryDSL` with `Spring Data Jpa` And I want to know how to make join on 3 table like :

```
AO(id_ao, ...)  
LOT(id_lot, id_ao, ...)
ACT(id_act, id_ao, ...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in `queryDSL` is like that

```
    new JPAQuery(entityManager).from(ao)
         .leftJoin( ao.LOTs, lot )
         .leftJoin( ao.ACTs, ac )
         .where(where).distinct()
         .list(ao);
```

`LOTs` is declared as `Set<LOT> LOTs = new HashSet<Fournisseur>(0)` in `AO` entity, the same goes for `ACTs`